# WebServer doesn't work until I switch the php version from 7.1 to 7.2 or 7.2 to 7.1

Tags: php, apache, web, server, version

i'm a newbie here, I have an issue with a server that I couldn't find an explanation. the webserver stops working untill I switch the php version i'm using ISPCONFIG webpanel and I should conenct go to sites and switch the php version and than the web server starts working again.

let me know if u need more informations.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

hello and welcome here :)

whats the exact error report if you switch the php-Version?

Answer (score 0):

please send us a php_info page as defined below:

[php_info](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.phpinfo.php)